# How to compare two dates using TeX primitives

Tags: conditionals, strings, comparison

This is a follow up to [TeX capacity exceeded while parsing a date string](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54594/tex-capacity-exceeded-while-parsing-a-date-string)

I want to compare two dates, say today's date and a due date. I have the due date information stored (as number strings) in macros `\dueday`, `\duemonth`, and `\duemonth`. I use the following, from `etoolbox` package:

```
\newcommand{\dueday}{6}
\newcommand{\duemonth}{5} % May
\newcommand{\dueyear}{2012}

\ifboolexpr{
    (test {\ifnumcomp{\dueyear}{>}{\year}})
    or (test {\ifnumcomp{\dueyear}{=}{\year}} and test {\ifnumcomp{\duemonth}{>}{\month}})
    or (test {\ifnumcomp{\dueyear}{=}{\year}} and test {\ifnumcomp{\duemonth}{=}{\month}} and test {\ifnumcomp{\dueday}{>}{\day}})
    }
    {Not due yet}
    {Due immediately}
```

which does work, but I'm looking for a TeX-based solution that, perhaps, can do this more efficiently and without having to use `etoolbox`.

Comment: You may want to try `\pdfstrcmp`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is doable using a series of pure number (`\ifnum`) tests, where the boolean logic is indicated by an 'outer' test which uses only 0/1:

```
\def\dueday{6}
\def\duemonth{5} % May
\def\dueyear{2012}

\def\notdue{Not due yet}
\def\duenow{Due immediately}

\ifnum
  \ifnum\dueyear>\year
    0 %
  \else
    \ifnum\duemonth>\month
      0 %
    \else
      \ifnum\dueday>\day
        0 %
      \else
        1 %
      \fi  
    \fi
  \fi
  > 0 %
  \expandafter\duenow
\else
  \expandafter\notdue
\fi

\bye
```

Comment: A pure TeX-based approach, so I've used plain TeX, hence the `\bye`.