# String parsing macro fails within a minipage environment?

Tags: environments, tex-core, parsing

I am trying to work with a string parsing macro, found in the answer of [TeX capacity exceeded while parsing a date string - TeX - LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54599/2595).

Basically, I have strings num01, num02... num09 - from these, I would like to extract the last character; and this code, for instance, works (with `pdflatex`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\parseMyNumHelper num0#1\relax{\edef\MyNum{#1}}
\def\parseMyNum#1{\edef\temp{#1}%
  \expandafter\parseMyNumHelper\temp\relax}

\begin{document}

  \edef\myid{num01}

%   \begin{minipage}
    \parseMyNum{\myid}
    \typeout{ ======== \temp === \MyNum }
%   \end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

... resulting with this in the log output:

```
...
 ======== num01=== 1
(./a.aux) )
...
```

However, now just uncomment the begin/end `{minipage}` statements; the code immediately crashes with:

```
...
(./a.aux
)
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \edef 
l.12     \parseMyNum
                    {\myid}
...
```

... and even if I proceed a bit with looking at `\parseMyNum`, I cannot see anything strange:

```
? i
insert>\show\parseMyNum
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   \show 
l.12     \parseMyNum
                    {\myid}
? i
insert>\typeout{ \meaning\parseMyNum }
 macro:#1->\edef \temp {#1}\expandafter \parseMyNumHelper \temp \relax 
> \parseMyNum=macro:
#1->\edef \temp {#1}\expandafter \parseMyNumHelper \temp \relax .
<insert>  \show\parseMyNum

l.12     \parseMyNum
                    {\myid}
```

Any ideas why the parsing macro `\parseMyNum` fails when within a minipage environment - and how to have a similar string parsing macro, working both within and outside of minipage and other environments?

Many thanks in advance for any answers,
Cheers!

Comment: `minipage` looks for its argument: `\begin{minipage}{width}...`

Comment: To confirm Ulrike's comment, if you put `\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}` then it works again.  (Admittedly, this is far from obvious when looking at the log file!  But a good debugging strategy is to *also* comment out the stuff you're trying to debug just to check that without it the document compiles okay.)

Comment: And indeed it is (looking for it argument) :) Many thanks for that @UlrikeFischer - would you mind posting your comment as an answer, so I can accept it? Cheers!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`minipage` looks for its argument: `\begin{minipage}{width}...`

Comment: Many thanks for that, @UlrikeFischer - wish sometimes Latex would be able to give a message like "`Error: environment minipage missing argument: \begin{minipage}...`"; instead of: "`Error: Missing number, treated as zero: \parseMyNum...`" ... but thankfully, it's solved now `:)` Cheers!

Comment: @sdaau: The argument is not missing. `minipage` is using your `parseMyNum` as argument  and tells you that it hasn't the correct content. You would get a similar error if you forget e.g. the  slash before a width: `\begin{minipage}{textwidth}`

Comment: Ah, I see - many thanks for that as well, @UlrikeFischer; I didn't come to the conclusion that "_minipage is using your parseMyNum as argument_" until now; it starts making a lot more sense. Could you also comment on why also forgetting the slash before a width would be similar? Is it that, not being a command, Latex will ignore the `{textwidth}`, and keep going until the next time it sees a backslash - a command, as demanded for `minipage`'s argument? Thanks again - Cheers!

Comment: No minipage will not ignore `{textwidth}`. It's its argument and it will try to use it. But the argument of `minipage` should be a *width* – in the end (after expansion) it should be a number followed by an unit like `cm` or `pt`. So if the argument start with "t" `minipage` will complain `Missing number`.