# Is it possible to parse a date string in LaTeX to convert it to a different date format?

Tags: datetime

I’m using svn-multi to include the date of the most recent Subversion commit of my documents. However, the string has the format `2013-10-13 11:05:51 +0200 (Sun, 13 Oct 2013)`. Is it possible to convert this string to the same date format that is used by `\today`?

Here is a minimal working example (Subversion inserts the date automatically before a commit):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{svn-multi}
\svnidlong
{$LastChangedBy: mcb $}
{$LastChangedRevision: 23 $}
{$LastChangedDate: 2013-10-13 11:05:51 +0200 (Sun, 13 Oct 2013) $}
{$HeadURL: http://example.org $}

\title{Sample Document}
\author{Sample}
\date{\svndate}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: I suggest you to follow this nice tutorial [here](http://www.howtotex.com/packages/customize-the-date-format-in-your-latex-documents/) There was also an equivalent question on tex.stackexchange [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31137/date-format-in-latex), and [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54594/tex-capacity-exceeded-while-parsing-a-date-string) for the parsing, that might help you. Should you have any further problem, please do not hesitate let us know. A Mininum Working Example ([MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-m

Comment: pgf/tikz has a date library which can parse dates. It cannot parse times, though. The parsed date can be reformatted as needed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's how to parse the date. The other answer gives links on adjusting the display:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datetime}

\def\parsecommitdate#1-#2-#3 #4:#5:#6 #7\endparse{%
  \date{\formatdate{#3}{#2}{#1}}%
}

\newcommand{\svndate}{2013-10-13 11:05:51 +0200 (Sun, 13 Oct 2013)}

\title{Sample Document}
\author{Sample}

\begin{document}

% Since \svndate is not available in the preamble the date must be set in the document environment.
\expandafter\parsecommitdate\svndate\endparse

\maketitle


\end{document}
```

Comment: This works really well, thank you. However, it does not work together with the `\svndate` (which just prints the date string). The error message is: `Paragraph ended before \parsecommitdate was complete.`

Comment: @mcb You need to expand `\svndate` before it can be parsed. It `\svndate` is a one level expansion of the formatted date you can just put `\expandafter` before `\parsecommitdate`.

Comment: It doesn’t seem to work with the MWE above.

Comment: @mcb It compiles fine for me. In what way does it not work for you? (Does it give an error message or produce unexpected output?)

Comment: @NicolaTablot Still the same error: `Paragraph ended before \parsecommitdate was complete.` (I just copied my MWE from above and added package, definition from your answer and replaced the line with the date.)

Comment: @mcb Can you edit your post to include a new MWE that shows this? What do you get if you do `\show\svndate`? If it doesn't show the date in the format you described, then you will get an error.

Comment: @mcb I just did another check. It looks like `\svndate` doesn't get set until `\begin{document}`, so make sure your code is in the document environment not in the preamble.