# Format date {yyy-mm-dd} as "mmm 'yy"

Tags: formatting, datetime, isodate

I have been struggling with this for some time, with combinations of the isodate and datetime packages, without success.

I would like to create a macro that receives an input in the format {yyyy-mm-dd} and returns "mmm 'yy". For example {2014-11-04} => Nov '14

I would also like for it to work for languages other than English.

Like a say, seems to be something that isodate could handle, and yet...

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}



\def\shortdate#1{\ifcase#1\relax\or
    Jan\or Feb\or Mar\or Apr\or May\or Jun\or
    Jul\or Aug\or Sep\or Oct\or Nov\or Dec\fi}

\def\mydate#1{\xmydate#1\relax}

\def\xmydate#1#2#3#4-#5-#6\relax{%
\shortdate{#5} '#3#4}

\begin{document}


\mydate{2014-11-04}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks David,

By far the most elegant solution I have seen.  I almost go there myself adapting the answer from [this post][1].

I used "datetime" to look up "\shortmonthname".

Parsing inputs like this is really powerful, but as a newbie the use of TeX primitives is a bit daunting.

  [1]: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/138617/33533